# Width of the caption of a figure

Tags: captions, width

I am having trouble making the caption beneath a figure to be of same width of the figure (less than the width of the paragraphs in the same page). How can I force the caption width to be the same as the figure width?

Comment: The magic word is MWE:  Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The `boxhandler` package will automatically make captions the same width as the figure/table, unless overridden (no width need be specified).  However, it requires you to enter figures/tables in macro, rather than environment form.  Examples: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101212/caption-format-changing/101217#101217 and/or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110393/too-wide-figure-caption/110453#110453

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) provides a `width` parameter than can be set for each figure individually. This way you can adjust the width to suit the width of your figure:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{graphicx,caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{width=.8\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth, height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-a}
  \caption[First figure]{\lipsum*[2]}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[t]
  \centering
  \captionsetup{width=.9\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=.9\linewidth, height=3\baselineskip]{example-image-b}
  \caption[Second figure]{\lipsum*[2]}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

If all your figures have the same width, you can set the option `\captionsetup{width=<len>}` globally.

Comment: Thanks werner for the quick answer.! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry. I get this error when I use the package {lipsum}, do you have any idea?

Comment: @Naema: Both [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) and [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) were just for this example. The latter is really not necessary in your document as it just creates dummy text, Lorem Ipsum-style. The former you might use, but then there should be no problem.

Answer (score 17):

Instead of using a predetermined width, one can measure the width using a savebox and put the caption inside a minipage.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\sbox0{\includegraphics{example-image}}% measure width
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\wd0}
  \usebox0
  \caption{\blindtext}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 13):

Probably the simplest solution is to put the figure in a `measuredfigure` environment, from the `threeparttable` package. Note however this environment is fragile and might require being protected:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{heuristica}
\usepackage[textwidth =15cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption, threeparttable}
\captionsetup{labelfont = sc, textfont = it}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering\captionsetup{format = hang}
\begin{measuredfigure}
\includegraphics{Piero_di_Cosimo_3}
\caption{Portrait of Simonetta Vespucci\label{sen}}
 \end{measuredfigure}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another, more powerful, possibility, consists in using the `floatrow` environment  and setting its optional width argument as `\FBwidth` (= float box width):

```
\documentclass [11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption} %
\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\captionsetup{font = small, labelsep = period}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{figure}[!htb] % <-- see difference between your code and this MWE
\centering
\begin{floatrow}[1]
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{Max Ernst: \emph{Two Children are treatened by a Nightingale} (1924)} \label{max_ernst}}%
{\includegraphics[scale = 0.75]{ernst-nightingale}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[14]

\end{document}
```

[image]