# Fit caption size to figure

Tags: captions, margins

I am using a latex template that uses a pretty big side margin. In order to be able to display images properly, it offers the option to extend images into that margin, the according width is stored in the constant `\widefigurewidth` which is calculated as `\def\widefigurewidth{\dimexpr(\marginparwidth + \textwidth + \marginparsep)}`.

However, it still fits the caption of the image to the textwidth:

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=\widefigurewidth]{black.pdf}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum ...}
\end{figure*}
Lorem ipsum...
```

Results in:
[image]

I tried explicitly setting the caption width:

```
\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \captionsetup{width=\widefigurewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\widefigurewidth]{black.pdf}
    \caption{Lorem ipsum ...}
\end{figure*}
Lorem ipsum...
```

This is the result:
[image]

Apparently, there is still some fixed margin to the right of the box that pushes it to the left. How can I override that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: A simple solution is always: Put it in a box and some hspace and hfill behind the box. Some puristic people here won't like it.

Comment: @Josef please have a look at the answer below if it meets the requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `minipage` environment and testing the image and caption for `textwidth` then `textwidth + marginparsep` and finally for `textwidth + marginparsep + marginparwidth`

Thanks to @JohnKormylo -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412713/197451

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\texttt{figure=textwidth}
\def\widefigurewidth{\dimexpr(\textwidth )}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=\widefigurewidth, height=2cm]{example-image}}% measure width
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\wd0}
  \usebox0
  \caption{\lipsum[66]}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\texttt{figure=textwidth + marginparsep}

\def\widefigurewidth{\dimexpr(\textwidth+\marginparsep)}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=\widefigurewidth, height=2cm]{example-image}}% measure width
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\wd0}
  \usebox0
  \caption{\lipsum[66]}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}

\texttt{figure=textwidth + marginparsep + marginparwidth}
\def\widefigurewidth{\dimexpr(\textwidth+\marginparsep+\marginparwidth)}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\sbox0{\includegraphics[width=\widefigurewidth, height=2cm]{example-image}}% measure width
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\wd0}
  \usebox0
  \caption{\lipsum[66]}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir! It did exactly what I wanted!